# Black screen with "System.String[]" and "OK" on Windows login

Tags: windows, windows-11, c#, login-screen

I've recently encountered a baffling phenomenon. From the Windows lock screen, pressing any key or mouse click *normally* brings up the password entry prompt. Instead, it shows a black screen with the large centered text reading "System.String[]", smaller text saying the exact same thing below it, and a button that just says "OK" below that. (Photo of screen included below.) If I click the button or press the Enter key, it then goes to the normal Windows login password entry screen; I can enter my password and log in normally.

This occurs anytime there is no user logged in, for example after boot, or after signing out from my user profile. (It does *not* happen if a user is signed in and simply locks the device.)

I am running Windows 11 Home 22621 on an Asus machine. Windows is completely up-to-date (on the Release channel; I do not use Insider channels).
I have run `sfc /scannow && dism /online /repair-image /restorehealth`, both of which report no issues.

[image]

I can think of a few recent events that could have *hypothetically* affected the system, although I don't recall this issue beginning immediately following any of them, so I don't particularly suspect them. I will list them here for thoroughness's sake, in case anyone recognizes something that could explain the behavior:

1. Upgraded Windows 11 21H2 (22000) to 22H2 (22621)
2. Compacted the OS (AKA ran `C:\Windows\System32\compact.exe /compactos:always`)
3. Installed Voidtools Everything Search v1.5.1-alpha, including its file-indexing Windows service (only mentioning this because it's an alpha build, so weird bugs happen. I've been using Everything Search's v1.4 production release for years without problem.)
4. Comodo Internet Security's HIPS virus protection feature misbehaved and started blocking random files and programs, including components of Windows and Comodo itself. This caused massive instability, with boot times lasting over an hour to desktop and explorer crashes. But as soon as I identified the problem, disabled HIPS, and unblocked all the files, the problems *completely* resolved. I have triple-checked that *all* the incorrectly blocked files, especially those that are Windows system files, have been restored. (For the record, I do *not* suspect any malware masquerading as a legitimate Windows files that HIPS was correctly blocking. I think it's much more likely that its heuristic algorithm decided to add "C:*.*" to the blocklist or something like that.

As you can see from the original issue description, this black screen and message is not causing any significant *problem* at the moment. However, I am curious what might have triggered it, and what might fix it. (*Please* don't recommend a system reset. I'm sure that would solve it, but this isn't worth a full reset. Besides, nuking the OS is a pretty intellectually hollow approach, don't you think?)

I know `System.String[]` is C# syntax, but given that this is Windows, that really doesn't narrow it down much. Any ideas?

Comment: When you press “ok” what happens?

Comment: It brings up the normal password entry screen, and I can log in like normal. (see last sentence of the first paragraph)

Comment: This means you have software installed that is causing the problem. I would start with Comodo Internet Security and Everything Search

Comment: It being a software problem seems like a reasonable assumption. Just curious, when you say, "This means...", is there something specific in what I've described that indicates a 3rd-party software issue?

Comment: If you are able to get to the logon screen it means a third-party application is displaying that text not Windows. So repairing Windows won’t resolve this issue.

Comment: Neato. I'll dig around and come back with an update when I find out what it is

Comment: (I guess I also could have confirmed it as a 3rd-party app issue by booting into safe mode)

Comment: Update: I still see this screen even when booting in Safe Mode, as well as after enabling the Ctrl+Alt+Del combo for the lock screen (which, as I understand it, is [intended to prevent any non-System program from displaying over the lock screen](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-ctrl-alt-delete-secure-sign-in-on-lock-screen-in-windows-11.1288/); specifically, this screen displays *after* I have pressed Ctrl+Alt+Del, which to me indicates that it *must* be some system process creating it...)

Comment: Windows is a conundrum at times, where things are impossible until they are possible unless you’re talking about specific elements that themselves conundrums. My point without being able to identify the application responsible for the behavior it’s impossible to explain the reason the behavior is possible

Comment: I don't disagree! I just am not certain now that it is a 3rd-party program, and not some system corruption. (BTW, if you don't mind upvoting this question, it would at least make it *slightly* more likely that someone else might see it who has relevant knowledge)